Unable to display a dataframe in VScode Jupyter notebook
I am trying to create a data frame in pySpark, but after writing all the steps properly, program throws an error at df.show() line
I created a new folder and opened it in VSCode. Then I went on to create a virtual env using the below commands
python -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate

Then I used the command pip install pyspark.
Then I created a new file named ques1.py for which the code is given below.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

sc = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .appName('example_spark')\
    .getOrCreate()

# creating a dataframe
data = [
    (1, "Gilbert Gathara", "24", "Nairobi"), 
    (2, "Someone Else", "32", "Nowhere")
]
headers = ("id", "Name", "Age", "Location")
df = sc.createDataFrame(data, headers)
df.show()

It throwed an error.
But after modifying the above code I was able to get the output. Modified code below:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import sys
import os


os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable

sc = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .master("local[*]")\
    .appName('example_spark')\
    .getOrCreate()

# creating a dataframe
data = [
    (1, "Gilbert Gathara", "24", "Nairobi"), 
    (2, "Someone Else", "32", "Nowhere")
]
headers = ("id", "Name", "Age", "Location")
df = sc.createDataFrame(data, headers)
df.show()

Output:
+---+---------------+---+--------+
| id|           Name|Age|Location|
+---+---------------+---+--------+
|  1|Gilbert Gathara| 24| Nairobi|
|  2|   Someone Else| 32| Nowhere|
+---+---------------+---+--------+

Then I went on to create a new file named ques2.ipynb:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

import sys
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('SparkByExamples.com').getOrCreate()

simpleData = [("James","Sales","NY",90000,34,10000), \
    ("Michael","Sales","NY",86000,56,20000), \
    ("Robert","Sales","CA",81000,30,23000), \
    ("Maria","Finance","CA",90000,24,23000) \
  ]

columns= ["employee_name","department","state","salary","age","bonus"]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
df.printSchema()
df.show(truncate=False)

But it throws an error:
root
 |-- employee_name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- department: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- salary: long (nullable = true)
 |-- age: long (nullable = true)
 |-- bonus: long (nullable = true)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 10
      8 df = spark.createDataFrame(data = simpleData, schema = columns)
      9 df.printSchema()
---> 10 df.show(truncate=False)

File c:\Users\abhkumarjha\Desktop\asd\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:945, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    885 def show(self, n: int = 20, truncate: Union[bool, int] = True, vertical: bool = False) -> None:
    886     """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    887 
    888     .. versionadded:: 1.3.0
   (...)
    943     name | Bob
    944     """
--> 945     print(self._show_string(n, truncate, vertical))

File c:\Users\abhkumarjha\Desktop\asd\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:976, in DataFrame._show_string(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    967 except ValueError:
    968     raise PySparkTypeError(
    969         error_class="NOT_BOOL",
    970         message_parameters={
   (...)
    973         },
    974     )
--> 976 return self._jdf.showString(n, int_truncate, vertical)

File c:\Users\abhkumarjha\Desktop\asd\.venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1316 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1317     self.command_header +\
   1318     args_command +\
   1319     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1321 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322 return_value = get_return_value(
   1323     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1325 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1326     if hasattr(temp_arg, "_detach"):

File c:\Users\abhkumarjha\Desktop\asd\.venv\lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    177 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    178     try:
--> 179         return f(*a, **kw)
    180     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    181         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File c:\Users\abhkumarjha\Desktop\asd\.venv\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2) (USBLRABHKU01.us.deloitte.com executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 34 more

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2856)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2792)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2791)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1247)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3060)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2994)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2983)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:530)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:4332)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:4322)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:546)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:900)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:4320)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:3314)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:280)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:315)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:331)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
    ... 34 more

This error is same as which I encountered in ques1.ipynb before including this.
import sys
import os

os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable

Python version: 3.8.10
pyspark version: 3.5.1

Did you try keeping master("local[*]")?

yeah, tried that. same error
